# I want to give out only one Argument instead of all 4

Tags: java, arguments

I want that the user can type four arguments, and this results that the numbers which the user typed in get summed up together. But now I have the Problem, if the user wants to give out less arguments. How do I sum up that?

```
public class Sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int  q = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int  w = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int  e = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int  r = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        int summe = q + w + e + r; 
        System.out.println(summe);
```

Comment: use Scanner instead of the command line arguments, and call them in a loop. ask the user whether he wants to input (more) data or not

Comment: Loop through `args` with a for-loop.

Comment: `System.out.println(Stream.of(args).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum());`

Answer (score 5):

You have to check the number of input arguments (i.e. `args.length`) in order not to try accessing invalid indices of the `args` arrays.

You don't need all of these variables if you only want to compute the sum:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
         sum += Integer.parseInt (args[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Why an indexed loop instead of an enhanced for-loop?

Comment: @khelwood no special reason. Both will do.

Comment: My answer to @khelwood would have been: To make correlation to question code clearer. ;-)